# ffmpeg -acodec and -vcodec parameter inputs list

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a list somewhere for ffmpeg which lists what the libraries we enter into the -acodec/ -vcodec parameters support?

eg: ffmpeg -vcodec x264 -acodec libmp3lame

I would like a list showing which formats x264/libmp3lame support.

Also is there a list that shows all possible inputs to the -vcodec & -acodec parameters.

Comment: why the -1? If, you could please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg -codecs` to get a list.

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs
Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 .....S = Lossless compression
 -------
 D.VI.S 012v                 Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 D.V.L. 4xm                  4X Movie
 D.VI.S 8bps                 QuickTime 8BPS video
 .EVIL. a64_multi            Multicolor charset for Commodore 64 (encoders: a64multi )
 .EVIL. a64_multi5           Multicolor charset for Commodore 64, extended with 5th color (colram) (encoders: a64multi5 )
 D.V..S aasc                 Autodesk RLE
 D.VIL. aic                  Apple Intermediate Codec
 DEVI.S alias_pix            Alias/Wavefront PIX image
 DEVIL. amv                  AMV Video
 D.V.L. anm                  Deluxe Paint Animation
 <snip>
```

In your case, it looks like you would be interested in this line:

```
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_crystalhd h264_v4l2m2m h264_vdpau h264_cuvid ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_nvenc h264_omx h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi nvenc nvenc_h264 )
```

and this line:

```
 DEA.L. mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3 mp3float ) (encoders: libmp3lame libshine )
```

If you want just the video codecs, you can filter them with 'V':

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep '^ ..V'
```

and audio with 'A':

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep '^ ..A'
```

The advantage of this method is that it shows you what codecs *your copy* of `ffmpeg` supports. There is also a list of codecs that the most recent version of `ffmpeg` supports here:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html

Related:

[Determine FFmpeg codecs available for container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973883/determine-ffmpeg-codecs-available-for-container)

[How can I determine if a codec / container combination is compatible with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276731/how-can-i-determine-if-a-codec-container-combination-is-compatible-with-ffmpeg)

https://superuser.com/questions/655951/which-codecs-are-supported-by-ffmpeg-libraries-in-system

Answer (score 0):

i have been searching for a while but no luck. you should search one by one.

becuase many containers support variety of codecs, but unfortunately, ffmpeg dose not support that perfectly. even if you can transcode, you can't playback it.

following link is which containers support what codecs. remind that this lists are not matched with ffmpeg perfectly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats

following lists are my tested results in ffmpeg 2.2, which containers support h264/mp3 codecs. perhaps this is what you want :)

H264(libx264) available containers : mp4, flv, ts, mkv, mts, mov, 3gp, 3g2

mp3(libmp3lame) available containers : mp4, wmv, flv, avi, mkv, mpg, mts, mov

Comment: Thanks for supplying me with the supported codecs for the two libraries I mentioned, but I was kinda hoping for a place where I could get something like the above for all the libraries ffmeg supports