# Determine FFmpeg codecs available for container

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am looking to generate lists of supported video / audio / subtitle tracks for each type of container in a particular build of FFmpeg.

For example, I want to avoid errors like `Could not find tag for codec <> in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`

I know I can list available codecs with `ffmpeg -codecs`, and find details about a muxer with `ffmpeg -h muxer=<muxer>` like `ffmpeg -h muxer=matroska` but that will only show default codecs, not all possible.

```
Muxer matroska [Matroska]:
    Common extensions: mkv.
    Mime type: video/x-matroska.
    Default video codec: h264.
    Default audio codec: vorbis.
    Default subtitle codec: ass.
```

Basically I want to run this command across all available muxers to build up a table like [wikipedia's format comparison charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Audio_coding_formats_support) that is FFmpeg build specific. This is designed to go in a program that wraps around FFmpeg, and I need to know which formats are valid for each container / file extension per FFmpeg build.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47276731

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for a possible solution! However, question / answer look to be interacting with ffmpeg's code directly? I will only have access to pre-comipled binaries.

Comment: There's no CLI codec list dump per muxer. I'll see about adding it but will take some time.